# jQuery ajax with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

JQuery’s AJAX “.get” method calls a (php page)method of a controller and the returned data is further processed….but then as we consider it a best practice, controllers are meant to just transfer control to the models and views..A controller never returns anything or echoes any data…so how can we support this argument? I may be wrong..still in the initial learning stages so pardon me if you find the question a bit too naive :(.

One eg. is JQuery’s autocomplete plugin that I was trying to implement which expects an array of users name from the database. Generally, with CI..the flow is View form -> Controller -> Database Model(DATA) -> Controller (DATA)-> Another view…but if I have to implement the JQuery/AJAX way then the controller will have to output data so that the AJAX calling function (get) can grab it. Right?

So what should be the flow without affecting the MVC paradigm?

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

MVC is just a design pattern. It tends to make things easier. But its a way of designing your applications, that doesn't mean you have to stick to it.

I work with Codeigniter and use controllers to reply to ajax. In my case the controller is in charge of receiving the request, and sending data back (just as if I was calling a view or template).

Don't overthink it, use what you want,when you want to, the way best fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The other option if you really want to stick to mvc is to have a view which you simply use for ajax responses.

You can either have it simply echo the response, or you can have it `json_encode()` you response if you are always going to be replying using json.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicolás points out, MVC is a design pattern, not law.

However, you should think of AJAX not as a *View* but as a transport, a medium through which communication between *Controller* and *View* or *Model* and *View* happens. Thus your actual *View* is not represented in PHP anymore but by the Browser itself, or rather its JavaScript code that you are running on it. You can abstract away the AJAX on the PHP side using an RPC server like the [Zend JSON-RPC Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.server.html).

Also note that for Web Applications, the Model-View-Presenter and similar patterns may be more useful as it keeps communication between View and Presenter.